# Problema al intentar rotar dos elementos en Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

estoy intentando hacer una funcion que cuando clickeo en una carta se dan vuelta las dos, ya que luego las quiero comparar. Para eso les agrego una clase llamada flip, que las rota 180deg. La cuestion es que no funciona, ya que al hacer click solamente se da vuelta la que fue clickeada, no la otra. A continuacion el codigo:

```
    const valor = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13];
   const palo = ['pick', 'corazon', 'trebol', 'carro'];


//creo un array de cartas
function crear(palo, valor, jugador) {
    let arrayCartas = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < palo.length; j++) {
        for (let i = 0; i < valor.length; i++) {

            let c = new Carta(valor[i], palo[j], jugador)

            arrayCartas.push(c);
        }
    }
    return arrayCartas;
}

//creo el obj carta
class Carta {
    constructor(valor, palo, jugador) {
        this.valor = valor;
        this.palo = palo;
        this.jugador = jugador
    }
 }
 
//creo el obj Mazo con varios metodos (mezclar,crear el html del mazo)...
class Mazo extends Carta {
    constructor(mazo, jugador) {
        super(valor, palo, jugador);
        this.mazo = mazo;
        this.jugador = jugador;
    }

    shuffle() {
        for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            var location1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * this.mazo.length));
            var location2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * this.mazo.length));
            var tmp = this.mazo[location1];

            this.mazo[location1] = this.mazo[location2];
            this.mazo[location2] = tmp;
        }
        return this;
      }

         htmlCards() {
            let elementoPadre=document.querySelector('div[datajugador="'+this.jugador+'"]');
            let deck=document.createElement('div');
            deck.classList.add('deck');
            elementoPadre.appendChild(deck);
            this.mazo.forEach(card=>{
                       
           deck.innerHTML +=`<div class="card" data-jugador="`+this.jugador+`" data-value="`+card.valor+`">
                                   <div class="front"></div>
                                   <div class="back">
                                    <div class="value">${card.valor == 1 ? 'A' : ''}${card.valor == 11 ? 'J' : ''}${card.valor == 12 ? 'Q' : ''}${card.valor == 13 ? 'K' : ''}${card.valor < 10 ? card.valor : ''}</div>
                                    <div class="suit ${card.palo}"></div>
                                     </div>`
            });
        }
    }

    let playerCard=document.querySelectorAll('[data-jugador="1"][data-value]');
    let pcCard=document.querySelectorAll('[data-jugador="2"][data-value]');
    let playing=false;
    
    
        function play(){
            this.classList.add('flip');
            pcCard[0].classList.add('flip');
          }
    
    playerCard.forEach(card=>card.addEventListener('click', play))
```

No se si se debe a superposicion de eventos, o algo del estilo, ya que cuando reeamplazo en "For Each" por la pcCard, la reaccion es similar pero al reves: la otra carta rota.

Este es mi codigo html:

```
<body>
<div class="pc" data-jugador="2"></div>

<div class="player" data-jugador="1"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: podiras subir el codigo html? me parece que tenes un problema con los querySelector

Comment: Ahi añadi el codigo javascript que crea codigo html y el codigo html original.

Comment: @JuandeTomaso podrías subir todo el código? adicionalmente el código js añadido cuenta con errores sintácticos

Comment: ahi va, saludos